# Pipe the output of a program as args into a Python script?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a script to take in the JSON output of some LXD containers in my infrastructure. LXD pretty-prints some JSON and I was to feed that JSON into my Python script.

```
python myscript.py | lxc list --format json
```

What can I do in my script to read this data correctly or have it handle this piped input?

## Attempt

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Comment: Have you looked at option parser yet? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/optparse.html

Comment: pipe goes the otherway (you are piping the python to lxc)

Comment: Whoops! Coffee hasn't kicked in yet haha. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is `pipe from | pipe to` so if you want to pipe lxc to python switch it to the other way

```
lxc list --format json | python myscript.py
```